# How to access the $_GET variables in my URL when running a separate php file (without using Session variables)

Tags: php, ajax

I am submitting my forms using ajax to a php file that processes the form data on the server. However I need to access the variables in the URL using $_GET but I'm getting the "Undefined index:" error message. I think it's because the current URL is not included (or viewed) in the php file because I submitted it separately with AJAX. I would prefer not to use session variables in this case. Any help is appreciated.

**URL**
../completeAccount.php?acctnum=433462524&keyCode=bdtF5ziKWJ

**Javascript**

```
formData = $(formID).serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    url  : "process.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data : formData,
        success: function(resp) {
            //success code
        }
});
```

**process.php**

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$newpass = $_POST['newpass'];
$newpass2 = $_POST['newpass2'];

$acctnum = $_GET['acctnum'];
$keyCode = $_GET['keyCode'];

//use variables to process data etc.
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What does your code **&** URL look like?

Comment: It depends upon how you are sending your ajax data. Try changing $_GET to $_POST and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I didn't think I needed to include my code but I edited my post so you can see it. Thanks

Comment: of course you need to show your code, and from it we can see there are no values send in the url `url  : "process.php",` which is why  $_GET is blank

Comment: Most likely you have created the ajax call the wrong way. Supplied a complete url with variables instead of a url and data in separate parts of the command. Without your code is it hard to tell. Why would you ask a question on a code solving forum without the willingness to show your code? You have to remove any sensitive information from your code of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the parameters with your javascript and append them into `formData`. The code that would grab a URL parameter might look like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Next, just append it into `formData`

```
formData = $(formID).serializeArray();
formData.push({name: 'acctnum', value: getParameterByName('acctnum')});
```

Note, that `acctnum` will then be in `POST`, not in `GET`!